# Sharing Common cart with all subdomain

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have created multi store view from backend.

1- store1

2- store2

Now when i add product from store1 and switch store view to store2 then it shows that added product from store1 into the cart. Now when i created two sub domains for store views

1-store1.mysite.com

2-store2.mysite.com

and configured it on store > configuration > web > store wise base url also made changes in host and vhost file of apache below is vhost configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@store1.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp72/htdocs/projects/mysite/pub"
    ServerName store1.mysite.com
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "store"
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "stoe1"
    ErrorLog "logs/store1.mysite.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/store1.mysite.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@store2.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp72/htdocs/projects/mysite/pub"
    ServerName store2.mysite.com
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_TYPE "store"
    SetEnv MAGE_RUN_CODE "store2"
    ErrorLog "logs/store2.mysite.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/store2.mysite.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

and did same thing add product from store1.mysite.com and switch to store2.mysite.com then it doesn't show that product into the cart.

Basically i want customer to share common cart for all store view with multiple subdomains.

Note: i also changed customer configuration Share Customer Accounts to global